# Tag adicionada sem relação com questão

Tags: debate, tags, edição

Bom, eu estava [acompanhando uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142070/reiniciar-comando-para-ver-se-houve-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-valor) no SOpt e até fiz uma edição, na tentativa de deixar mais clara e objetiva.

Um usuário, que inclusive estava respondendo a dúvida, editou a pergunta também e adicionou a tag `jQuery`, porém, em momento algum o autor da postagem menciona o uso de `jQuery`, somente do código em `PHP` e a tag `JavaScript`, que o mesmo havia colocado já no início da questão.

A resposta do usuário possui sim uma solução em `jQuery`, mas a questão nunca menciona isso.

É correto editar novamente a pergunta removendo a tag `jQuery`? Ou tratar a questão de outra maneira?

Comment: Acho que já tivemos uma discussão sobre isso aqui.

Comment: @JorgeB. onde? Pois não consegui encontrar nada relacionado.

Comment: @JorgeB. a discussão em questão foi essa: [Posso colocar uma tag na pergunta por causa de uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1984/3117) Mas como a resposta foi "depende", acredito que deve ser tratado caso a caso. Eu acho...

Comment: @Math pois é.. Pois a questão pode não ter apenas uma resposta, especialmente pelo fato de que jQuery é só uma opção. Pode se obter os mesmos resultados apenas com uso de JS. Mais difícil e trabalhoso, mas possível.

Comment: @Math era essa mesmo.

Comment: Lendo bem a pergunta, não acho que a tag seja válida, uma vez que o OP em momento algum apresentou nada em relação a JQuery.

Comment: Colocando a tag jQuery, ele esta limitando as diferentes opções de respostas que poderia receber, restringindo/_obrigando_ o uso do jQuery em respostas. Ao meu ver, essa edição foi supérflua, apenas para adicionar uma tag.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142070/reiniciar-comando-para-ver-se-houve-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-valor#comment294276_142070

Comment: Essa situação é a mesma desta que eu respondi http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4182/3635, o "respondedor" não entende que as tags devem ser sobre o problema e não sobre a solução.

Comment: Fui eu que respondi, à primeira vista a pergunta paraceu-me só ser para fazer reload à página, depois o AP disse-me que era só para fazer reload ao elemento da página que deveria ficar, tudo bem que me posso ter precipitado ao editar e colocar a tag de jquery. Foi para conseguir responder simples/perceptivel (em termos de codigo), foi só por motivos didáticos para que ficasse mais intuitivo. De qualquer maneira eu teria retirado a resposta/tag se a intenção do AP fosse fazer esta funcionalidade mesmo com JS nativo

Comment: Até agora o AP não disse nada que afastasse o uso de jQuery, só o fiz para ser mais facil explicar/entender, poderia te-lo feito com JS nativo mas duvido (dada a aparente experiência do AP) que fosse o fosse ajudar.

Comment: Mas @Miguel sua resposta e sua abordagem não estavam erradas. Era uma solução boa. A questão era só o uso da tag jQuery na 'Pergunta' também. Pois usando a tag, pode dar a entender que o autor só deseja soluções naqueles moldes. Como ele deixou apenas php e js, diversas soluções seriam possíveis, como a sua própria resposta.

Comment: Eu sei @CelsomTrindade Talvez não tenha sido o mais correto 'impingir' jQuery ao AP, mas se respondesse com jQuery sem este estar nas tags iriam secalhar comentar coisas tipo: "O AP não disse que era com jQuery", ou até mesmo negativar resposta por isso (responder com jquery sem este estar nas tags). O meu propósito era ajudar o colega, e que ele ficasse a perceber, obviamente que se ele dissesse que não podia ser com jQuery eu retiraria emediatamente a resposta/tag... E agora o que faço? Restauro a resposta mas não se coloca a tag jQuery? Só queria ajudar

Comment: Eu não retirei as tags originais, só acrescentei, não limitei as respostas, até possibilitei mais @Florida ... Mas, como já disse, se ele não quisesse/pudesse usar jquery eu retiraria. O que faço? Restauro a resposta?

Comment: Acredito que sim @Miguel, esses comentários são "irrelevantes", como não foi especificado que "não pode ser jQuery" nada impede de ser. Acho que você deve restaurar, pois sua resposta servia para solucionar o problema e modo prático. Eu só levantei a questão aqui pois não sei como tratar esse tipo situação, não estou criticando a sua resposta nem sua atitude de adicionar a tag, só quis entender também hahahaha :)

Comment: Não acho que precisasse excluí-la, o que se questionou foi só a tag.

Comment: Entendi. RestauradA a resposta obgado